# Microsoft Excel Autoformat Atheltic Running Numbers

Tags: excel, time, numbers, format, autoformat

I'm trying to find a way to autoformat numbers in Excel so that I can type something like 21557 and see it as 2:15:57. (Yes this is a h:mm:ss format and I want to see it as this but it doesn't have to be true time. I'm not using as a calculation rather as a ranking with other runners.)

I have tried a number of ideas and all fail as Excel tries to correct the time.  I've tried the following custom formats:

h:mm:ss (this does work but I have to enter the semicolon between the numbers in order for the format to appear right plus the formula reads 2:15:57 AM for some reason)

0:00:00 is invalid

#:##:## results in 0

attempting to alter ##'.'## as #'.'##'.'## results in 21557'.''.'

trying to alter each cell as a time function is ridiculously time consuming and not feasible

Open to any and all ideas because I'm stumped.

Comment: How about `0\:00\:00` ? It won't be true time but should be sufficient for ranking against similar entries.

Comment: are you open to a macro enabled worksheet?

Comment: Yes but I am open to marcos but...

Comment: Jeeped! I could hug you through the computer!  Yes this worked.  Thank you so much.

Comment: The backslash is an escape character that makes the following character literal rather than interpretive. The custom number format mask could also written as `0":"00":"00`

Answer (score 0):

Try in a new field:

```
=+TIME(LEFT(A1,1),MID(A1,2,2),RIGHT(A1,2))
```

Then apply `h:mm:ss` format.